# app goes into background mode after running video for sometime

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, avplayer, ios13

I have a simple app which streams live video from a server and me using AVPlayer. Now my concern is, after playing the video for 20-30 min the app automatically goes into background mode, even though there is no crash or exception.

The behaviour is - app running in foreground mode and video playing and then suddenly the app goes into background mode.

Since I have registered for "UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification" and hence come to know app goes to background mode. I'm not sure how the BackgroundNotification is getting triggered automatically even user does not press home-button at all.

Is there any delegate method or callback which makes the app go into background mode?

thanks

Comment: try to disable idle timer during playing

Comment: @Nick - idle timer of avplayer or app  ?

Answer (score 0):

That is not the background mode, that is screen lock. You can prevent the device from locking screen using this:

```
UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
```

Don't forget to set it to `false` again once you reach the end of the video or if user leaves the player view.